# Entity Framework - return the database value or create a new instance (nav property)

Tags: entity-framework

My setup is as follows: Entity Framework POCO (+ proxies & lazy loading). And a `Person` class with reference to `Address`:

```
public class Person
{
    private Address _address;
    /* Navigation property */
    public virtual Address Home 
    {
        get
        {
            return _address;
        }
        set
        {
            _address = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this is a `0..1` property and can be `null`. The question is - how can I create a new instance of Address if it is `null`. Lazy loading does not create a new instance aumatically (and it shouldn't) and if I rewrite the getter as follows it just always creates a new `Address`:

```
    private Address _address;
    /* Navigation property */
    public virtual Address Home 
    {
        get
        {
            if(_address == null) Address = MyContext.CreateObject<Address>();
            return _address;
        }
        set
        {
            _address = value;
        }
    }
```

So if never actually goes from `null` to a real value like this (I am guessing that this has to do with EF lazy loading & proxy property overloading mechanism). Checking for `null` in the constructor also does not help - same outcome - always creates a new `Address`.